# Create account and transfer usdt into the wallet adress. Used block chain to search address. Why was the adress used before i created my account?

Tags: blockchain, address-reuse, contracts, futures

There is an app i was led to called kzzy. You can fund your account with btc, eth, and usdt. All crypto converts to usdt once transferred to account. I am given two wallet addresses to send crypto to. An eth adress which matches usdt adress and a btc adress. When I search these addresses in a blockchain explorer I discovered more transactions than i have made. There are transactions that exist on the wallet adresses before i created the kzzy account. Also its like a futures exchange, you bet a contract high or low on btc with usdt; however i do not have any record of contract transaction #. I also cannot find any record of the contract bids place on this kzzy app on the blockchain. I Only see tranfers from my peronal wallet to the kzzy acount wallet and also gas fees.

My two questions are
-can a wallet be reused safely?
-Will the blockchain have transaction records from futures trade pool contracts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **can a wallet be reused safely?**

A Bitcoin address can be re-used *safely* but doing so damages privacy.

> **Will the blockchain have transaction records from futures trade pool contracts?**

Typically that kind of activity takes place off chain. It may require an initial Bitcoin transaction to transfer funds into an account provided by a market operator of some sort. It may eventually use a Bitcoin transaction when you decide to withdraw funds from that account. But those two events are usually distinct from your "futures trade pool contracts" which typically do not use the Bitcoin blockchain.

Since Bitcoin has a scripting language, there is potential for many sorts of complex arrangement. Some might involve multi-signature transactions etc. But nodes typically don't relay non-standard transactions.

It is also possible to embed arbitrary data in a Bitcoin transaction (for example see BRC-20). So it would perhaps also be possible to embed details of "futures trade pool contracts". Normal Bitcoin nodes would effectively ignore the meaning of this data. Many blockchain explorers might not make it visible in any meaningful way.